# How to add a button to react-date-range

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-datepicker

```
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';

<DateRangePicker
   onChange={(item) => { this.handleonDateRange(item)}}
   showSelectionPreview={true}
   moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
   months={2}
   ranges={this.state.dateRange}
   direction="horizontal"
/>
```

And the image is [image]

How can I add an Apply button in the bottom right corner ?? So that when the user clicks on Apply button I can hide the calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a option to provide a button in react-date-range as of now,
But we can enclose DateRangePicker inside a Bootstrap React-Modal and we can add a button in Bootstrap React-Modal

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to the date range picker in the component in which you are using the library. Check out this Netlify link.

https://luminous-taiyaki-7232a8.netlify.app/

The code for the above project is below:

```js
const Calendar = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState([
        {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: addDays(new Date(), 7),
            key: 'selection'
        }
    ]);
    let [changeText, setChangeText] = useState(false);
    const handleChange = () => {
        return setChangeText(!changeText);
    };
    var str = JSON.stringify(state[0].startDate);
    var strone = JSON.stringify(state[0].endDate);
    var month = parseInt(str.substring(6, 8).replace(/['"]/g, ''));
    var monthone = parseInt(strone.substring(6, 8).replace(/['"]/g, ''));

    const arr = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "December"];
    console.log('newstate123', str);
    let a = parseInt("012");
    console.log('newstdfugbdfufv', a);
    return (
        <div >
            {console.log('newstate', state)}

            <button className='border rounded' onClick={() => handleChange()}>
             {str.substring(9, 11).replace(/['"]/g, '')}-
             {arr[month - 1]}-{str.substring(0, 5).replace(/['"]/g, '')}-----
             {strone.substring(9, 11).replace(/['"]/g, '')}-{arr[monthone - 1]}-
             {str.substring(0, 5).replace(/['"]/g, '')}</button>

            {changeText ? <div className='rangepicker my-4'>

                <DateRangePicker
                    onChange={item => setState([item.selection])}
                    showSelectionPreview={true}
                    moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
                    months={1}
                    ranges={state}
                    direction="horizontal"
                    preventSnapRefocus={true}
                    calendarFocus="backwards"
                    className='calendar'

                /></div> : " "}

        </div>
    )
}

export default Calendar
```